# Variable $questions no esta definida

Tags: php, laravel

necesito mandar una variable que contiene los valores de mi base de datos, hacia un metodo POST. intente con el with pero me marca un error que dice que no se encuentra mi variable. La variable que estoy enviando es $Data2

este es mi controlador:

```
public function save(Request $request){

        $validator=$this->validate($request,[
            'Sede'=>'required',
            'Alcance'=>'required',
            'Nombre'=>'required',
            'Cierre'=>'required',
            'Areas'=>'required'
            
        ]); 
        $request->merge([ 
            'Areas' => implode(',', (array) $request->get('Areas')),
            'preguntas' => implode(',', (array) $request->get('preguntas'))
            ]);
   
           
        $user=Project::create($request->all());
        $data2['questions'] = Questions::paginate(5);
        return back()->with('datosGuardados', 'Datos almacenados, Correctamente')->with(null,$data2);
    }
```

y este es el segmento de codigo donde lo quiero poner para ejecutar un foreach. El error esta en el foreach por que me dice que no se encuentra la variable, pero se supone que le estoy pasando la variable en el controlador.

```
<form action="{{ route('save') }}" method="POST">
                @csrf

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 mt-5">
                        <select name="Sede" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                            <option selected name="Sede">Campus Sede</option>
                            <option value="Cancún">Cancún</option>
                            <option value="Chihuahua">Chihuahua</option>
                            <option value="Ciudad Juárez">Ciudad Juárez</option>
                   
                        </select>
                    </div>

                   

                    <div class="col-md-6 mt-5">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Areas[]"id="ingenieria" value="Ingenieria" />
                        <label for="ingenieria">Ingeniería</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Areas[]"id="humanidades" value="Humanidades" />
                        <label for="humanidades">Humanidades</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Areas[]"id="negocios" value="Negocios" />
                        <label for="negocios">Negocios</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Areas[]" id="salud" value="Salud" />
                        <label for="salud">Salud</label>
                    </div>
                    <!--PRUEBA PARA LEER LAS PREGUNTAS DE LA BASE DE DATOS.-->

            
                  @foreach($questions as $question)
                    
                  <div class="col-md-6 mt-5">
                        <label for="">{{$question->name}}</label>
                        <input type="text" name="Nombre" class="form-control col-md-14">
                    </div>
                  @endforeach
                 

                    <div class="row form-group mt-5">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-md-2 offset-5">Guardar</button>
                    </div>
            </form>
```

Haciendo lo que me comenta, me marca este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el problema esta en el foreach, no esta definida la variable $questions, pero le estoy pasando $data2 en el with

Comment: jaja, si la estoy mandando

Comment: ah y como mando un solo campo de la tabla de mi base de datos?

Comment: no, no me sirvio. no entiendo por que no me funciona si ya lo hice con otros y no hubo problemas

Comment: de acuerdo, voy

Comment: Lo pude resolver usando PHP y otro metodo, pero aun asi gracias por su apoyo 

Comment: ok, muy bien gracias

Answer (score -2):

lo que hice fue:

- quitar el foreach y anexar este codigo en php

De esa forma ya tomaba los datos correctamente por el metodo  get y no obstruia el método post

```
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                }

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM questions";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["pre"].  "</td></tr>";
                }
                $conn->close();
```

Comment: Si estás usando Laravel, para qué creas tu propia conexión mysqli? Lo que acabas de hacer es como si alguien te regala un Ferrari y le quitas todo el motor para meter el de una vespino :)

Comment: Pues al no tener una mejor solucion es lo que me queda, quizas despues de todo un Sleeper no sea tan mala idea